# Chrome replaces the decimal point commas in input type="number"

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

https://jsfiddle.net/ky6h0tpf/

```
<input id="input" type="number" lang="en">
document.getElementById("input").value = 10.5;
```

lang="en" works for FF, but not for Chrome.

https://jsfiddle.net/ky6h0tpf/1/

```
<input id="input" type="number" lang="en">
document.getElementById("input").value = 10.5;
```

Comment: Chrome replaces the decimal point to the comma.

Comment: <input id="input" type="number">
document.getElementById("input").value = 10.5;

Comment: Can you point what your question exactly is?

Comment: How to disable the replacement of the decimal point to the comma?

Comment: This is browser internal locale behavior - so it is up to browser how to hsow numbers. If you really want to control your options are - choose lang with decimal separator you satisfied with or use text input. Having some custom js will allow you to be in full controll of what user may put in there.

Comment: @Dmitry lang="en-US" is a lang with decimal separator?